# Very slow performance of spring-amqp comsumer

Tags: spring-amqp

I've been experiencing troubles with spring-boot consumer. I compared the work of two consumers.
First consumer:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recv {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                     AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            }
        };

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
    }
}
```

Second consumer:

```
@Controller
public class Consumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "hello")
    public void processMessage(Message message) {
    }
}
```

There are no config files for spring-boot consumer installed, everything goes by default.
On my computer first one works 10 times faster. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The default prefetch (`basicQos`) for Spring AMQP consumers is 1 which means only 1 message is outstanding at the consumer at any one time; configure the [rabbitListenerContainerFactory `@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-enable) to set the prefetchCount to something larger.

You will have to override the default boot-configured `@Bean`.

Comment: Thanks. I see you are new here - it will help others searching for answers if you "accept" the answer (click the tick/check mark on the left below the vote buttons).